# How to make a desc order in sqlite?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I have tried to desc the order of the below list:

```
select name from tbl_name WHERE chapterid= ORDER BY name Desc
```

but some times not desc order after colon numbers. So how to desc both 2011 : 10. Is it possible to do that. Please let me know.

Below I have mention Table column value for your reference

```
SKL 2005:9
SKL 2011:10
SKL 2011:35
SKL 2001:76
SKL 2000:2
```

Comment: Your question is hard to read. What are you trying to achieve exactly? The second code block...is that the current output or the desired output?

Comment: Actually above given table value

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for arranging first years in desc order then corresponding numbers after **':'** again in decending order. May be below query will help you.

```
SELECT name
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER  BY  to_number(SUBSTR(Name,5,INSTR(name,':',1)-1-4)) , 
           to_number(SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,':',1)+1, LENGTH(name)-INSTR(name,':',1)))
DESC
```

output:

```
SKL 2000:2
SKL 2001:76
SKL 2005:9
SKL 2011:35
SKL 20011:10
```